# DOCTRINE PDO postgresql bindValue() with null -> SQLSTATE[22P02]

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, pdo, doctrine-orm

I am banging my head on the wall with **PDO PostgreSQL** and **PHP** (+ some **DOCTRINE** and **SYMFONY** - but I don't use ORM)

At some point I have a **null** value that I want to use in the bindParam() function.

It goes like:

```
$sqlReadyToBindValue->bindValue(':an_integer_field',null,PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

And I ve tried also with:

```
$sqlReadyToBindValue->bindValue(':an_integer_field',null,PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

In both cases it raises an exception:

**SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: """ at [SYMFONY FOLDER]\vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 91**

I don't get it because any other thing I do with the bindValue() function goes thru.

I notice reading the log that my **null** value **becomes two simple quotes** when going thru **DOCTRINE**, something like:

at DBALException ::driverExceptionDuringQuery (object(Driver), object(PDOException), `'SELECT an_integer_field FROM a_table WHERE an_integer_field = :an_integer_field', array(':an_integer_field' => ''))` 
in vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\Statement.php at line 17

and then:
at AbstractPostgreSQLDriver ->convertException ('An exception occurred while executing '`SELECT an_integer_field  FROM a_table WHERE  an_integer_field  = :an_integer_field`  ' with params [""]: SQLSTATE[22P02]: Invalid text representation: 7 ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: ""', object(PDOException)) 
in vendor\doctrine\dbal\lib\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException.php at line 116

Then it raises the first Exception, I've wrote on earlier: AbstractPostgreSQLDriver.php line 91 (the one that splashes on the screen)

Any clue? **Is there maybe a way to make sure null doesn't become quotes in DOCTRINE**?

Comment: Nulls are not integers so I don't see this can work.  sql uses the IS NULL operator to check for null values.

Comment: @Cerad, yes it does make sense:) Also since the field, being an integer, accept the value null, it lead me to think that binding null could work in a WHERE statement. I found a work around, that I'll post as an anwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a work around by using the 'IS null' check in the SQL query instead of binding a parameter to it.